# Different dimension for different language

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a project, where in the textview the dimension of text is mentioned in a file main_dimens.xml in values-1024x768 folder. But i need a different text size for specific language(say pt).

```
<dimen name="main_digitalclock_size">18dp</dimen>
```

I need 12dp for pt language. So i tried to add the above line of code in strings.xml of values-pt folder, also created a folder values-pt-1024x768 and putted in it. But still size is 18dp only.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you named your resource folders correctly? I looked up the rules that the Android OS uses when determining which resources to use here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

It looks like the way to specify the usable screen size may be different from what you're using.